# generate a Zip file from azure blob storage files

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, azure, azure-blob-storage

I have some files stored in my windows azure blob storage. I want to take these files, create a zip file and store them in a new folder. Then return the path to the zip file.
Set permission to the zip file location so that my users can download the zip file to their local machines by clicking on the link

```
 https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/2b5f8ea6-3dc2-4b77-abfe-4da832e02556/AppList/isjirleq/mydocs1.doc
 https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/2b5f8ea6-3dc2-4b77-abfe-4da832e02556/tempo/xyz/mymusic.mp3
 https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/2b5f8ea6-3dc2-4b77-abfe-4da832e02556/general/video/myVideo.wmv
 https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/myfiles/2b5f8ea6-3dc2-4b77-abfe-4da832e02556/photo/photo1.png
```

I want to be able to loop through these files and zip them all together to create a new zip file

(`https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/myzippedfiles/allmyFiles.zip` ) and return the path to the zip file

I have a large number of files in my azure blob. So downloading, zipping and uploading them is not a good idea.

How can I do this? I need some sample code to do this

Comment: This answer mentions putting them in Azure Local storage, but doesn't explain exactly how..yet http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587660/creating-a-zip-file-in-situ-within-azure-blob-storage

Answer (score 39):

We have solved this problem (partially) by zipping the files directly to the output stream using the blob streams. This avoids the issue of downloading zipping then sending and avoids the delay while this happens (we used ICSharpZipLib, [reference](https://github.com/icsharpcode/SharpZipLib/wiki/Zip-Samples)). But it still means routing the stream through the web server:

```
  public void ZipFilesToResponse(HttpResponseBase response, IEnumerable<Asset> files, string zipFileName)
    {
        using (var zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(response.OutputStream))
        {
            zipOutputStream.SetLevel(0); // 0 - store only to 9 - means best compression
            response.BufferOutput = false;
            response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + zipFileName);
            response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                var entry = new ZipEntry(file.FilenameSlug())
                {
                    DateTime = DateTime.Now,
                    Size = file.Filesize
                };
                zipOutputStream.PutNextEntry(entry);
                storageService.ReadToStream(file, zipOutputStream);
                response.Flush();
                if (!response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                   break;
                }
            }
            zipOutputStream.Finish();
            zipOutputStream.Close();
        }
        response.End();
    }
```

The storage service simply does this:

```
public void ReadToStream(IFileIdentifier file, Stream stream, StorageType storageType = StorageType.Stored, ITenant overrideTenant = null)
    {
        var reference = GetBlobReference(file, storageType, overrideTenant);
        reference.DownloadToStream(stream);
    }
private CloudBlockBlob GetBlobReference(IFileIdentifier file, StorageType storageType = StorageType.Stored, ITenant overrideTenant = null)
        {
            var filepath = GetFilePath(file, storageType);
            var container = GetTenantContainer(overrideTenant);
            return container.GetBlockBlobReference(filepath);
        }
```

Comment: I know this may be tough to answer, but any sense for how long this takes based on the number/size of the files? I'm looking at zipping up a container full of 50-200 images (each about 5-7MB) into a single zip for someone to download. Before I go down this route I'd be curious if your experience is if building that zip could take 30 seconds, or 10 minutes or even longer?

Comment: In this circumstance the zip file is written directly to the response stream so actually the download starts as soon as the file stream is written to. So the delay is negligible and as long as you can read and zip the data faster than it is being downloaded (which you can in most situations). Which is why we did it this way.

Comment: Wow, it didn't even register with me that you were streaming the response back in that code, but it makes sense. Obviously, that's what you originally said now that I re-read your answer ;) Very cool approach!

Comment: For net core: Use `response.Body`, make sure to install the preview build of SharpZipLib (compatible with netstadnard) and remove code that gives syntax errors (`BufferOutput` for example)

Comment: Can I use the azure functions to zip the files and upload back to blob storage? If possible can you give some insights?

Comment: What is the performance gain from using this approach, I don't think there is a  significant gain especially when zipping many small files since the only benefit here is there is no reading and writing them to disk which is a negligible percentage of the total time compared to the download/upload time.... anyone got some numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Since blob storage is **"just"** an object store, you would need to download them somewhere (it could be a web/worker role or your local computer), zip them and then reupload the zip file. That's the only way to do it as far as I know.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can avoid downloading them, zipping them locally, and uploading them back.

Compression utilities work with local resources only.  Azure Storage itself has no concept/ability of being able to compress some files by itself

Answer (score 3):

I'd be 99% sure that whatever zip library you're using will require local resources/local files in order to create a zip file.

Have a look at Azure Local Storage for Worker Roles.

http://vkreynin.wordpress.com/2010/01/10/learning-azure-local-storage-with-me/

You'll be able to specify an amount of local storage within your worker role in order to save content accessible in process.

e.g.

//Create a Local Storage section in your config.

```
<WebRole name="...">
 <LocalResources>
   <LocalStorage name="myLocalStorage" sizeInMB="50"/>
 </LocalResources>
</WebRole>
```

//Then save your files to local storage

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("myfiles");
CloudBlob blob = container.GetBlobReference("2b5f8ea6-3dc2-4b77-abfe-4da832e02556/AppList/isjirleq/mydocs1.doc");

LocalResource myStorage = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("myLocalStorage");
string filePath = Path.Combine(myStorage.RootPath, "mydocs1.doc");
blob.DownloadToFile(filePath);
```

Once you've got all your files saved in LocalStorage, use your ZipLibrary to bundle up all your file paths together

Comment: I would actually recommend using an `Azure Drive` for this purpose instead of local storage. First, an `Azure Drive` can be up to 1 TB (thus much bigger than local storage) and second, the data once written to a drive is persisted.

Comment: Well he said he wants to put it back the zip back in BlobStorage. so presumably he doesn't want to persist things twice. But yeah, an Azure Drive would work assuming he needs the additional space.

Comment: I would skip Azure Drive. The zip operation is point-in-time: Download a few files to local disk, zip up, push back to a blob. If the local disk fails during operation, no worries - just use a queue message to persist the "zip up these files" command. Plus, if you use Azure Drives, you need one disk per role instance; this seems like a lot of effort for little-to-no gain.

Comment: agree. The maximum amount of storage you can assign is limited by the particular VM size so the only reason to go "azure drive" would be if you have particularly large zip files/file contents to process by a relatively small worker role

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use webjob or worker role to do it. When you receive a user's request, push this request into queue, then return the job id to user. Webjob or worker role fetch the request from queue, and download these files and zip them, then upload the zip file back to Storage blob. Front side code can use ajax roll polling with the job id to get the real download url when it is done.

Answer (score 0):

I have done this Using JSZip from website to download a multiple files from Azure Blob Storage

```
var urls = [
"images/20170420_145140.jpg",
"images/20170503_142841.jpg",
"images/20170503_084035.jpg"];


download() {

    urls.forEach(function (url) {
        JSZipUtils.getBinaryContent(url, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                throw err; // or handle the error
            }
            try {
                zip.file(count + ".jpg", data, { binary: true });
                count++;
                if (count == urls.length) {
                    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
                        FileSaver.saveAs(content, zipFilename);
                    });
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("errorrr...k", e)
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score -1):

dont think azure provides any out of box functionality for zipping.If you need to avoid turnaround time maybe.using a background worker role be a good idea which will pick your files from certain queue.zip them upload them and store url for you somewhere like sql db.I have done similar things while communicating with db so you can be assured it will work very fast without user realising that its actually not happening at front end.