# Azure ZIP multiple files using Shared Access Signature and download from stream

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

### Is it somehow possible to zip multiple files directly to the output stream using Shared access signature and then send it to user?

---

I'm using [Shared Access Signatures](https://azure.microsoft.com/sv-se/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-shared-access-signature-part-1/) for downloading blobs from my blobstorage and [DotNetZip](http://DotNetZip) for zipping the blobs, (or trying atleast).

```
   var images = _fileService.GetImages(companyID, model.ImageIDs).ToList();

        if (images != null && images.Count > 0)
        {
            DateTime currentTime = TimeZoneExtensions.GetCurrentDate();

            using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
            {
                MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream();

                foreach (var image in images)
                {
                    if (image.ImageLinks != null)
                    {
                        //ImageLinks contains SAS uri for each image format..
                        List<ImageLinkModel> imageLinks = image.ImageLinks.Where(m => m.FormatID == model.FormatID).ToList();

                        if (imageLinks != null && imageLinks.Count > 0)
                        {
                            foreach (var imageLink in imageLinks)
                            {
                                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(imageLink.DownloadURL) || imageLink.DateExpiresDownloadURL < currentTime)
                                {
                                    int hours = 1;

                                    imageLink.DateExpiresDownloadURL = currentTime.AddHours(hours);

                                    //Create new shared access signature
                                    imageLink.DownloadURL = _fileService.GetDownloadImageURL(imageLink.BlobName, image.ImageName, hours);

                                    //Update imagelink
                                    _fileService.UpdateImageLink(companyID, imageLink);

                                    //Exception here
                                    zip.AddDirectory(imageLink.DownloadURL);
                                }
                                else
                                {

                                    //Use existing SAS download url

                                    Exception here
                                    zip.AddDirectory(imageLink.DownloadURL);
                                }
                            }

                            zip.Save(output);
                        }
                    }
                }

                return File(output, "application/zip", "sample.zip");
            }
        }
```

This is what I have come up with so far.

When running this method and adding a file to the zip I get the exception:
`System.ArgumentException URI format not supported`. I assume you can only add local path to the zip which makes sense, so now I'm out of ideas.

This is one of my SAS URLs:

http://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/images/22201642127PM625F493A7418BA855265516DF8038?sv=2015-04-05&sr=b&sig=%2FdNy6l6qyn7H1fh4D8T1Rd7emzgs%2B4GgQFlPoCOwBW4%3D&st=2016-02-05T09%3A35%3A04Z&se=2016-02-05T10%3A50%3A04Z&sp=r&rscd=Attachment%3B%20f...

It's nothing wrong with the URL, (I can download without zipping).

Am I trying to do the impossible here? Am I forced to download the blobs the normal way like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852389/generate-a-zip-file-from-azure-blob-storage-files) and after that zip them?

Thanks

Comment: Did you intend to add the file as a directory in the Zip? If not, try adding it as a file instead. If so, there's a logical flaw: even if there was a canonical way of representing a directory over HTTP (which AFAIK there isn't), Blob Storage doesn't actually have the concept of directories. You can get a directory reference from the client library, but unless I'm mistaken, it simply provides an abstraction for "list all blobs whose names start with this".

Comment: I have a page where users can select which images to download. If the user selects more than one image I want to add every image to one zip file and send it back to the user. I'm not sure what you meant with directory in the zip.. Somehow I need to download all the images from the SAS urls and insert them into the zip..

Comment: You are calling ZipFile.AddDirectory(). That _adds a directory_ to the zip. You are passing to it a uri string that does not represent a directory.

Comment: Aha. I tried .AddFile instead of AddDirectory but it still gave me the same ArgumentException

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as Azure sees blob storage is just a boundary with some bits and bytes in it. It has no concept of file types, or handlers to do anything with them. (and neither does HTTP)

You are hoping for intelligence in the storage that doesn't exist. The only thing you can do with the URI is to download it,

So yes you need to download it, then zip it then send it wherever its going.

Comment: Arguably, he's hoping for intelligence in the Zip library. ;-)

Comment: @Rytmis although, it would be a really useful feature request ;)