# azure blob download via SAS

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-blob-storage

All,

I have a blob container with nested filenames (simulating a folder).

Is it possible to download via code (bypassing the webserver) through SAS URI for a bunch of files beginning with a prefix?
Right now, i am zipping these files and sending it to a stream below..

```
  CloudBlobContainer container = GetRootContainer();
  CloudBlockBlob caseBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(folderPrefix);
  await caseBlob.DownloadToStreamAsync(zipStream);
```

This works and i can download the set of files beginning with that prefix to a client machine. However this is dependent on the webserver's speed and its comparatively slow.

Is there an example on how to download using SAS by providing a URI for the folder? Here is an example i found from another post in stackoverflow

```
var sasConstraints = new SharedAccessBlobPolicy();
sasConstraints.SharedAccessStartTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5);
sasConstraints.SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(10);
sasConstraints.Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read;

var sasBlobToken = blob.GetSharedAccessSignature(sasConstraints);

return blob.Uri + sasBlobToken;
//Here can the URI point to the prefix??
```

Can i use something like this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure I'm clear on what you're trying to do.  Download files from blob storage, but what do you mean by 'bypass server'?  Server side code uses the blob storage sdk to generate SAS links which expire.  Do you need SAS links that do not expire and that can be statically placed and accessed somewhere else?

Comment: My web app is running on the azure server and when i download it goes through the server to download to the local pc and as a result its slow..

Comment: Doesn't the server just generate the download link, then the client goes out and gets the file from blob storage directly?

Comment: Yes,but how would you do it, if you have to download multiple files into one folder for a client?

Comment: very similar to what the user is trying to do [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35221462/azure-zip-multiple-files-using-shared-access-signature-and-download-from-stream)

Comment: agreed, sounds like the same thing

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly doable however it won't be a single step process.

First, you can't have a SAS Token for a virtual folder. You will need to get a SAS token for the blob container with both `List` (for listing blobs) and `Read` (for downloading blob) permissions.

Next you will list the blobs in the virtual folder inside the blob container. In order to do so, you will need to specify the virtual folder path as the prefix. This will give you a list of blobs inside that virtual folder. Please ensure that you specify empty string as delimiter so that all blobs inside that virtual folders are listed.

Once you have the list of blobs, you will need to read (download) the blobs and store the blob content somewhere in the browser.

After you have read the blob contents, you could use a JS based zip library to dynamically create zip file contents and once all the blobs are added to the zip file, you can force download of that zip file. A quick search for JS based zip library landed me here: https://stuk.github.io/jszip/. When I implemented this functionality in a product I built, I used ZipJS library but unfortunately I am not able to find it online though now.

Bits and pieces of the code I wrote many years ago (it was part of a much larger application + there was no JS Storage SDK when I wrote it so apologies if the code does not much sense to you. Please use it for general guidance only).

```
    zip.workerScriptsPath = '/Scripts/ZipJS/';
    zipWriter = new zip.BlobWriter();
    zip.createWriter(zipWriter, function (zipWriter) {
        startZippingFiles(zipWriter);
    }, function () {

    }, true);


function startZippingFiles(writer) {
    if (downloadedContent.length > 0) {//downloadedContent is an array containing downloaded blobs
        var downloadedContentItem = downloadedContent.shift();//read first item
        var cloudBlob = downloadedContentItem.Blob;//get the cloud blob object
        var blobContents = downloadedContentItem.Content;//get the blob's content
        var status = downloadedContentItem.Status;//status to track blob's download status
        if (status === 'Completed') {
            writer.add(cloudBlob.name,
                new zip.BlobReader(new Blob([blobContents], { type: cloudBlob.properties.contentType })), function () {
                    console.log(cloudBlob.name + ' added to zip...')
                    downloadedBlobsCount += 1;
                    startZippingFiles(writer);
                }, function (o) {
                    console.log('Adding ' + cloudBlob.name + ' to zip file. ' + parseFloat((o * 100) / cloudBlob.size).toFixed(2) + '% done...');
                });
        }
    } else {
        writer.close(function (blob) {//Finally save the zipped data as download.zip
            saveAs(blob, "download.zip");
            zipWriter = null;
        });
        console.log("Download successful!");
    }
}
```