# How to create zip file in logic app using blobs

Tags: zip, azure-logic-apps, connector

I need to create a zip file using blobs, but I'm not able to achieve it. I found no connector that could do it. I saw somewhere to use the function to achieve this requirement, but I don't know where and how use this function. Does anyone have any clue about an example where you did this?

I was trying to find any connector that can help but I believe there is no standard method that can help.

Comment: You can write an Azure function instead of Logic App.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a small Azure Function App that  you can configure on blob trigger or interval (whichever trigger you are thinking for logic app).

Azure function will be more simpler here.

[generate a Zip file from azure blob storage files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18852389/generate-a-zip-file-from-azure-blob-storage-files)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).